# Balancing multicols with non-stretchable parskip

Tags: multicol, parskip

I want to use `multicols` with `\parskip` fixed to `\baselineskip` (i.e. without stretchable glue) in order to get a two column document with grid typesetting.

The problem is that when I want to insert content with a height that is not a multiple of `\baselineskip` (like images or environment with different fontsizes) the balancing at `\end{\multicols}` fails.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\parskip 1\baselineskip

\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1-2]

\vspace{0pt plus 1\baselineskip}
{\footnotesize \lipsum[3]}
\vspace{0pt plus 1\baselineskip}

\lipsum[4]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Even though I manually inserted glue around `{\footnotesize \lipsum[3]}`, the balancing doesn't work.

[image: balancing problem]

Answer (score 1):

One can use `\parbox` to force odd sized blocks to fit into a given number of `\baselineskip`s.  However, you first have to know how many `\baselineskip`s to use.  In addition, LaTeX uses a different rule when the depth and height of 2 consecutive lines are more than `\baselineskip`.  When the last line has no descenders, you need to add about about `.3\baselineskip` (depending on `\lineskip`}.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\parskip=1\baselineskip
\lineskip=1pt

\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1-2]

\parbox[c][\dimexpr 13.3\baselineskip][c]{\columnwidth}{\footnotesize \lipsum[3]}

\lipsum[4]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force `multicol` to try a bit harder by adding

```
\setcounter{columnbadness}{2000}
```

before the environment.

[image]